# getting user's vicinity without showing map with google maps api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use HTML5 to get users lantitude and longitude. All ok.

How can i get users location's `vicinity`using Google Maps v3 ?

I read about Places library of Maps api v3

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=lat,lng&radius=500&&sensor=false&key=my_key

how can i get the output from this URL and parse it ?

thanks

Comment: While you can use the Places API without a map, you do need to use the Google logo as specified in the docs. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Limits [I'm sure you were going to do that, but it's as well to mention it explicitly for others who use this question and answer]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I made $.POST to internal PHP page.

and in this PHP page, 
i get the contents of google service with `file_get_contents` and output it. Then i get the output data by $.POST and parsed it JSON parser. Finally, i got the user's vicinity.